# What is [visual-studio-2008-db] for?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Probably a bit of a stab in the dark, but...

Does anyone know what [visual-studio-2008-db](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008-db) is for?

I saw [database-edition](/questions/tagged/database-edition) which seems to predominantly be referring to "Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition".

Is [visual-studio-2008-db](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008-db) referring to the same?

I looked at some of the questions, but couldn't tell one way or the other (there are definitely some that uses it as Database Edition, but others I'm not sure about).

Since I don't know what it means, it's fairly likely that some people who used it misused it.

It's probably no big loss if we remove all of them, or replace them with [database-edition](/questions/tagged/database-edition), since there's only 9 questions tagged.

Also, I was considering renaming [database-edition](/questions/tagged/database-edition) because it's ambiguous and misused - maybe to something like [vs-database-edition](/questions/tagged/vs-database-edition) and maybe [visual-studio-database-edition](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-database-edition) as a synonym.

Any generic advice for my thoughts for possible course of actions?

PS: It seems there are also other versions of Database Edition, but I don't think it's popular enough to have a tag for each version, using [visual-studio-2008](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008) or similar along with it should be sufficient.

Comment: [tag:visual-studio-2008-database-edition] is 10 characters too long to be a tag.

Comment: @icktoofay Oh, I wasn't aware there's a limit / didn't think about it. Good to know.